# Unapply a config that was applied with `apply -f`

Tags: kubernetes

I have applied a config file like this `kubectl apply -f deploy/mysql.yml`

How can I unapply this specific config?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use kubectl delete command

```
kubectl delete -f deploy/mysql.yml
```

Comment: Thank you! I will accept your answer in 9min (stackoverflow is blocking me)

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to do that: `Error from server (BadRequest): error when deleting "deploy/mongo.yml": admission webhook "mongodb.validators.kubedb.com" denied the request: mongodb "default/mongo" can't be paused. To delete, change spec.terminationPolicy`

Comment: You are using `deploy/mongo.yml` Did you have this applied?

Comment: I think I do because when I try running `kubectl apply -f deploy/mongo.yml` again I get: `mongodb.kubedb.com/mongo unchanged`

Comment: Looks like you have the `terminationPolicy: DoNotTerminate`. Please edit the deployment with `terminationPolicy: Resume`.

Comment: Thanks! I removed that line, re-applied it, then deleted it!